# Training a single neuron perceptron on Matlab

Tags: matlab, perceptron

I am required to train a single neuron perceptron which classifies two different classes. 
I wrote this code on matlab.

```
function error = train_perc( PercepClassTraining,eta,weights )

%initialization:

xZero=1;
wZero=0.1;

t=1; % round number
x=[];
y=[];
error=[];
epoch_error=[];
c=1;

    n=1;
    x1=PercepClassTraining(n,1);
    x2=PercepClassTraining(n,2);
    y(n)=(xZero*wZero)+(x1*weights(1))+(x2*weights(2));
    error(n)=PercepClassTraining(n,3)-y(n);


while(error(n)~=0)
        weights(1)=weights(1)+(eta*error(n)*x1);
        weights(2)=weights(2)+(eta*error(n)*x2);


        if(n==2000)
         epoch_error(c)=mean(error);
         error=[];
         c=c+1
         n=1;
        else
            n=n+1;

        end

        y(n)=(xZero*wZero)+(x1*weights(1))+(x2*weights(2));
        error(n)=PercepClassTraining(n,3)-y(n);

end
```

Where eta is learning rate, and PercepClassTraining is the training set (2000 inputs).

It converges at epoch #58 when I use 0.1 for learning rate and [0.01 0.01] for initial weights, and that doesn't use all the training set.

When I set eta to 0.01 and weights to 0.1, 0.1 it loops forever! Is there anything wrong in the code? How about the stopping criteria?

Comment: Your algorithm may not be converging because the error may **never** be zero.  Did you try using a threshold instead? (i.e. `while error(n) < tol`, where `tol` is some small number like `tol = 1e-10`).

Comment: I think the algorithm allows to reach an error of zero only, is that right?

Comment: Not necessarily.  That totally depends on your data, your weights and the activation function.  Consider the [`XOR Problem`](http://home.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/xor_t/en/main.htm).  This can't be solved using a single neuron and it actually needs two layers.  You need to double check your data to see if it can really be classified with one neuron.

Comment: The data are 2 classes linearly separable. The instructor asked for single layer single neuron.

Comment: So do I have to use the step function or any other activation functions?!! I am confused about the perceptron and the delta rule.. Whats the difference?